# ¿Como quitar el resaltado amarillo en PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Actualmente me encuentro probando Phpstorm con un proyecto el cual trabajo diariamente pero ultimamente algunas partes de codigo se ven resaltadas en amarillo en todo el proyecto y ya resulta ser un poco fastidioso ¿saben que manera puedo quitar ese resaltado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando pones el puntero del mouse o el cursor encima, qué te dice? Ese marcado suele indicar un warning o una opción de mejora que phpstorm te está sugiriendo...

Comment: No me refiero el amarillo del warning que se encuentra debajo de mi codigo me refiero a lo que lo resalta por ejemplo si ves en la imagen que compartí aparece valor = 1 * vu; el "1 * vu"; se ve un resaltado en amarillo, igual al pasarle el cursor solo me aparece "1 * vu can be replaced with vu"

Comment: Por eso. El resaltado "por debajo" es un warning. El resaltado "en bloque" es porque hay sugerencias.

Comment: ¿Se puede quitar el resaltado en bloques?

Comment: no te recomiendo quitarlo; te recomiendo o que cambies tu seting de patrones de diseño para php o que te apeques a uno...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta donde recuerdo, eso es un tipo de inspección. Creo que es un weak warning.

De acuerdo a [la documentación](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections), la solución es que desactives la inspección o inspecciones. Se puede desde el bloque marcado, debe salir un bombillito, lo seleccionas y debe tener la opción de gestionar la inspección, omitirla, apagarla, etc. O en la configuración de PhpStorm

(primera vez que veo que alguien no quiere que le ayuden ;)  )